# Screen stays black after installing new graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, blank-screen

I brought a new graphics card to put into my computer, but when I turn the computer on, the screen still stays black but I can still hear the sound.

It is a PCI-e Card.

- Graphics card: NVIDIA G210
- Motherboard: NVIDIA ZOTAC Motherboard Series
- RAM: 1GB
- Power source: 380W

Answer (score 1):

Did you plug your monitor in to the correct port?

When you have a graphics card, you have to (usually) use the monitor ports on that. If you are still not seeing anything, or this s what you have done, try using the ports on the motherboard and see if there are any settings in the BIOS you need to change.

Lastly, if you are doing it correctly, but before you were using VGA and now you are using HDMI/DVI e.t.c. check on your monitor to see if there is an input selection button as you may have to switch between the input types.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I Already plugging in the correct port and still not work. maybe my graphics card is broken.